# How to support masking in custom tf.keras.layers.Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing a custom `tf.keras.layers.Layer` that needs to support masking.

Consider the following scenario

```py
embedded = tf.keras.layer.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size + 1, 
                                    output_dim=n_dims, 
                                    mask_zero=True)
x = MyCustomKerasLayers(embedded)
```

Now per the documentation

> `mask_zero`: Whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding" value that should be masked out. This is useful when using recurrent layers which may take variable length input. **If this is True then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception will be raised**. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim should equal size of vocabulary + 1).

I wonder, what does that mean? Looking through [TensorFlow's custom layers guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers) and the [tf.keras.layer.Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) documentation it is not clear what should be done to support masking

1. How do I support masking?
2. How do I access the mask from the past layer?
3. Assuming input of `(batch, time, channels)` or `(batch, time) would the masks look different? What will be their shapes?
4. How do I pass it on to the next layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To support masking one should implement the `compute_mask` method inside the custom layer
2. To access the mask, simply add as the second positional argument in the `call` method the argument `mask`, and it will be accessible (ex. `call(self, inputs, mask=None)`)
3. This cannot be guessed, it is the layer's before responsible to calculate the mask
4. Once you implemented the `compute_mask` passing the mask to the next layer happens automatically - excluding the case of model subclassing, which in this case it is up to you to calculate masks and pass them on.

Example:

```py
class MyCustomKerasLayers(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, .......):
        ...

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        # Just pass the received mask from previous layer, to the next layer or 
        # manipulate it if this layer changes the shape of the input
        return mask

    def call(self, input, mask=None):
        # using 'mask' you can access the mask passed from the previous layer
```

Notice that this example just passes on the mask, if the layer will output a shape different than the one received, you should change the mask accordingly in `compute_mask` to pass on the correct one

#### EDIT

Now explanation is also included in the [`tf.keras` masking and padding documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/masking_and_padding).

Comment: but what if the output shape is different from the input shape?

Comment: So you will have to update the mask, you should manipulate it in the `compute_mask` and return the new one with the new shape

Comment: I don't know what the new mask should look like in compute_mask. Is it for example, if this is a rnn problem, let's assume we pad all the sequences to sen_len. Suppose the input has shape (batch_size, seq_len, feature_dim) and output shape(batch_size, seq_len, feature_dim/2). what is the mask look like before and after compue_mask.  Am I allowed to ask questions like this in the comment? Or should I just open a new question?

Comment: The mask is one rank lower than the input, so if you have `(batch_size, seq_len, channels)`, the mask will usually be `(batch_size, seq_len)` - so in your specific example you won't be needing to change the mask since the same indices of irrelevant information are kept (along the second axis)